# Gulp won't build js

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to build from a js source folder to a destination folder using gulp (I'm considering adding lint during the process)

But for some reason it doesn't copy the files over.

I want it to copy the files from folder jssrc/ to js/ but the js/ folder always remains empty.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),

    lessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    lessAutoPrefix= new lessPluginAutoPrefix({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
    }),

    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    pkg = require('./package.json'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

function getLocalUrl() {
    try {
        return fs.readFileSync('custom-vhost.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                return data;
            } else {
                return "http://dev.vhost.dev/site/";
            }
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        return "http://dev.vhost.dev/site/";
    }
}

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: getLocalUrl()
    });
});

gulp.task('build-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['jssrc/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
            gutil.log(error.message);
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    return gulp.src(['less/**/*.less', '!_mixins.less', '!_variables.less'])
            .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
                gutil.log(error.message);
                this.emit('end');
            }))
            .pipe($.less({plugins: [lessAutoPrefix]}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
            .pipe($.notify("CSS files created!"));
});

gulp.task('build-js', function() {});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    runSequence(['build-css', 'build-js'], function() {
        console.log('Build Complete!!');
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('less/**/*.less', ['build-css']);
    gulp.watch("jssrc/**/*.js", ['build-js']);

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: getLocalUrl()
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build'], function() { });
gulp.task('browser', ['build', 'browser-sync', 'watch'], function () {});
```

Comment: Does it throw your error or does it 'complete' but not copy anything?

Comment: does your `build-css` task work? what is your project structure?

Comment: You are overwriting your `build-js` task  after ``build-css`` task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're overwriting your `build-js` task with the empty one. Try removing the following line:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function() {});
```